How to tell `pip` the path to includes and libraries
I have a python package that I install with the following two commands:
python setup.py build_ext -I ~/install/include -L ~/install/lib -R ~/install/lib
python setup.py install

With this it works perfectly, except for a deprecation warning which I want to solve.
I want to change the setup.py file, or whichever has to be modified, so that it can be installed with pip install path/to/package. I have tried tens of possibilities with setup.py and pyproject.toml and none of them works. Some things I have tried:
setup.py:
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from pathlib import Path
import os

extensions = [
    Extension(
        name = "mypackage", 
        sources = [Path(__file__).parent/"mypackage/*.pyx"],
        language = "c++",
        libraries = ['mypackage'],
        library_dirs = [(Path.home()/'install/lib').resolve()],
        include_dirs = [(Path.home()/'install/include').resolve()],
        runtime_library_dirs = [(Path.home()/'install/lib').resolve()],
    ),
]

setup(
  name="mypackage",
  version = '0.0',
  description = "Python interface for the mypackage library",
  classifiers = [
      'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
      'Intended Audience :: Developers',
      'Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux',
      'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
  ],
  author = 'My Self',
  author_email = 'my_self@hotmail.com',
  packages = ["mypackage"],
  package_data = {'mypackage': ['*.pxd']},
  ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, language_level=3)
 )

pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", 'Cython']
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.extension]
include_dirs = ["~/install/include"]
library_dirs = ["~/install/lib"]
runtime_library_dirs = ["~/install/lib"]

I also tried with absolute paths /home/myself/install/include and the same for lib.
The command
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/home/myself/install/include" --global-option="-L/home/myself/install/lib" --global-option="-R/home/myself/install/lib" .

taken from the answers to this question, installs the package, but produces the same deprecation warning that I mention at the beginning of the question, so it is not a solution.

This question does not seem to say what the issue that needs solving is. Is there any error message? What is the problem?
